# Replace only certain numbers using sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have to replace `1` with `one`, `two` with `2` and so on but 11, for example, has to stay unchanged. Using

```
sed -i 's/1/one/g'
```

filename also changes 11.

I don't know how to check line by line and only change what I need. Is there any other way?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change with sed, is it part of a larger command/script, does it really need to be done with sed?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.3

Comment: We'll need an example of your input and desired output - it *may* be sufficient to use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) e.g. `sed 's/\b1\b/one/g'` or `sed 's/\<1\>/one/g'`

Comment: @steeldriver I don't know if anything better can be done in `sed`, and agree the OP should post a sample input. Your suggestions don't convert e.g. `any1` into `anyone`.

Comment: this is completely unclear imho. We have no idea which numbers you want to change and "replace `1` with `one`, `two` with `2` " is ambiguous to say the least!

Comment: @Zanna Question is unclear, incomplete and OP hasn't logged in in a while...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with **`perl`**:

```
perl -lpe 's/(?<!\d)1(?!\d)/one/g' test.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `perl` scripting language that excels at text processing
- `-l` deal sensibly with line endings
- `p` automatically print each line
- `e` execute the following command
- `'` start of instructions
- `s/` substitute
- `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind: the match must not follow a digit
- `1` literal `1`
- `(?<!\d)` negative lookahead: the match must not be followed by a digit
- `/one` substitute with literal `one`
- `/g` substitute all matches
- `'` end of instructions

**Test:**

```
perl -lpe 's/(?<!\d)1(?!\d)/one/g' test.txt > test1.txt
head test*.txt
==> test.txt <==
1
11
111
a1
1a
1a1

==> test1.txt <==
one
11
111
aone
onea
oneaone
```

**Update:** To automatically change `1-9` with `one-nine` you can

1. write out all substitutions

   ```
   perl -lpe 's/(?<!\d)1(?!\d)/one/g;s/(?<!\d)2(?!\d)/two/g;s/(?<!\d)3(?!\d)/three/g;s/(?<!\d)4(?!\d)/four/g;s/(?<!\d)5(?!\d)/five/g;s/(?<!\d)6(?!\d)/six/g;s/(?<!\d)7(?!\d)/seven/g;s/(?<!\d)8(?!\d)/eight/g;s/(?<!\d)9(?!\d)/nine/g;' test.txt
   ```
2. use a `perl` array

   ```
   perl -lpe '@a=qw(zero one two three four five six seven eight nine);s/(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)/$a[$1]/g' test.txt
   ```
3. loop over the one-liner with `bash`

   ```
   NUMBERS=(zero one two three four five six seven eight nine)
   for i in "${!NUMBERS[@]}"; do
       perl -i -lpe 's/(?<!\d)'$i'(?!\d)/'${NUMBERS[$i]}'/g' test.txt
   done
   ```

Comment: what about "replacing `two` with `2`? Question is unclear, we don't really know which numbers OP wants to change apart from 1 and 2... I've voted to close the question